# App Engine ndb StructuredProperty __get__

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

OK, I'm stuck. I have a simple `StructuredProperty` (just one level deep) property on an entity. And at runtime, I want to get the value of one of the "sub-properties" on that `StructuredProperty` by name. For example;

```
class Address(ndb.Model):
  street = ndb.StringProperty()
  # ...

class Person(ndb.Model):
  # ...
  address = ndb.StructuredProperty(Address)
```

and then at runtime I want to be able to do something like:

```
prop = entity._properties['address']
sub_prop = prop.__getattr__('street')
value = sub_prop.__get__(entity, Person)
```

or get at it using `GenericProperty` or whatever works best. But I have tried a number of variations and I am clearly missing something. Of course the reason I want to do this is there are really a number of named `Address`-like `StructuredProperty` and I know which one I want based on runtime context.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What's wrong with `getattr(prop, 'some_name')`? I'm having trouble with this one.

Comment: You were right Bobby. I was looking at it backwards. Had to step away from the computer and come back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bobby was right. I was getting at the property, not the property value the way I was thinking (long day).

The simple answer is

```
getattr(prop, 'some_name')
```